# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

WordPress Stack Exchange's [third moderator election](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the three new moderators are:

[image: kaiser] [image: s_ha_dum] [image: Tom J Nowell]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4705950703288320/0).

Comment: Congrats new mods!

Comment: saha dum dum i like this name though :)

Comment: Congrats guys. Welcome abord

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to our new admins!!!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Good wishes in Bangla]

Answer (score 2):

## Congrats to our new Mods. Can't wait to see them in action.

Oh wait, they already are!!!

Answer (score 2):

I for one welcome our new overlords.

[image: Kent Brockman -- ant overlords]

Answer (score 2):

Thank goodness nobody voted for web dude.

[image]

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRGljemfwUE

Answer (score 1):

I am happy to see all three of my voted candidates were elected. Congrats all three of you, you have earned it :-)